# UIButton doesn't receive touch after CAKeyframeAnimation

Tags: ios, uibutton, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

My situation:
I've a `UIButton` that it's animate with a `CAKeyframeAnimation` that's declared as a category on `UIView`:

```
    CAKeyframeAnimation * scale =  [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    scale.duration = duration;
    scale.beginTime = delay;
    scale.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

    NSMutableArray * times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    scale.values = values;
    scale.timingFunctions = times;

    CAAnimationGroup * group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    [group setDelegate:self];
    [group setDuration:duration + delay];
    [group setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [group setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    [group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObject:scale]];

    [self.layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"scale"];
```

The problem is that after the animation, the button doesn't receive touch. If I remove the animation all works fine.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Glad this post exists :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must insert the following line of code `self.layer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(finalScaleX, finalScaleY);` when the animation is ended.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use kCAFillModeForwards and removedOnCompletion = NO to stick the animated layer in the final position. This will not work for a control, and results in the behavior you noticed.

Instead, set the final state for the button before adding the animation to it's layer.

```
self.layer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(finalScaleX, finalScaleY);
[self.layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"scale"];
```

Comment: The animation scale the frame from `initialScale = 0.001f` to `finalScale = 1.0f`. So, if I set `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(finalScaleX, finalScaleY)` the result is that the button start from large, then is reduced end final larger again. But this isn't the animation I'm looking for.

Comment: Maybe UIControls act somehow special with their layers (and animations of them). UIImageViews can also be tricky and are often better replaced by UIViews drawing the image in drawRect.

You could try to move the line:
self.layer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(finalScaleX, finalScaleY);

to the animationDidStop:finished: delegate method.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the animation only changes the presentation of the button but the touch target is still the same as before. You should either remove the animation after completion and set the transform on the button or ht test the presentation layer.

I wrote about [hit testing animating layers in a blog post](http://ronnqvist.tumblr.com/post/21228285860/hit-testing-animating-layers) that explains it in more detail.